# Help with inaccessible embedded resource issue

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, .net-3.5, resx

There are two programs that are very similar in code for the same purpose, and one of their functions is launching a winform.

The main difference between them is that one is 'targetted' to .NET 3.5 (and so uses 3.5 methods/conventions) and the other is a .NET 4.0 project (does same thing with newer methods)

the 3.5 project can launch the winform fine, but the 4.0 project reports that the icon '$this.Icon' embedded within the form's .resx file cannot be found.

Is there a key difference between 3.5 and 4.0 that could be causing this? Maybe 4.0 is stricter about naming conventions and doesn't like the dollar sign?

I've imported the code file that calls the form from 3.5 to my 4.0 project and that still throws a file not found error :(

error message : Could not load file or assembly 'Olympic.Braindump.OutlookPlugin2010.resources, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=en-US, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

part of the stacktrace : `at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalGetSatelliteAssembly(String name, CultureInfo culture, Version version, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.GetSatelliteAssembly(CultureInfo lookForCulture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.GrovelForResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Dictionary`2 localResourceSets, Boolean tryParents, Boolean createIfNotExists, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)

Comment: the problem may be that on the .net 4 project it is referencing an assembly that doesn't exist rather than a class, but I don't know how to stop that happening.

Comment: By default, VS likes to make the project ".NET 4 Client Profile" which breaks a lot of things as the "client" is a small subset of .NET 4. Ensure that you chose ".NET Framework 4" and not ".NET Framework 4 Client Profile." in the project properties.

Comment: As I had to use a System.Web component, I already targetted it to the full version of .net 4, I am afraid that is not the cause of this issue.

Comment: Similar error in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69707339/concurrency-issue-when-loading-satellite-assembly