# Concurrency issue when loading satellite assembly?

Tags: c#, .net-5, system.reflection, asp.net-core-localization

In our CI, we sometimes get the following error:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly '<our-assembly-name>.resources, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=en-US, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.
    at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(ObjectHandleOnStack assemblyName, ObjectHandleOnStack requestingAssembly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, ObjectHandleOnStack assemblyLoadContext, ObjectHandleOnStack retAssembly)
    at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyName, RuntimeAssembly requestingAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, AssemblyLoadContext assemblyLoadContext)
    at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalGetSatelliteAssembly(CultureInfo culture, Version version, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound)
    at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetSatelliteAssembly(CultureInfo culture, Version version)
    at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetSatelliteAssembly(CultureInfo culture)
```

So far we've never seen this exception in production or on a local development machine. It only occurs on the CI during test execution (using `dotnet test` with `xunit` as testing framework and `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0.401` as base image). Since we see this error only now and then and most of the tests run in parallel, so I'm led to believe that this might be a concurrency issue.

Does anybody have an idea what would be the cause of (and thus also the remedy for) this?

**Some context**: what we are trying to achieve in our code is to get the stream for a localized resource. So we are doing something like:

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
    .GetSatelliteAssembly(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(language)); // this sometimes crashes
using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))  { ... }
```

where `language` in this case is "en-US".

Comment: If you're running multiple `dotnet test` instances in parallel, you might need to add the `--no-build` option, to prevent that you have parallel builds at the same time as parallel test runs.

Comment: @PMF unfortunately, I'm not. I'm first doing a `dotnet build` followed by a `dotnet test <our.csproj>` and there-in, the error is thrown.

Comment: Hmm, still I would try whether `--no-build` fixes the issue. You don't need to (attempt to) build a second time.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the culprit was a test that was using the `Buildalyzer.Workspaces` package (v3.2.3) which in turn uses Roslyn (`Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces`) to compute certain code statistics.

I've noticed a crash of the test host in that test and so I've decided to disable it for the time being. Since then, we also haven't seen the satellite assembly look-up raise a `FileNotFoundException` anymore. I'm assuming that somehow the "parallel build" that Roslyn does interfered with the running tests.

I don't have a proof for this but this is what the experience shows. Also, if a activate the test again, other sporadic problems start showing up again (including the `FileNotFoundException`). It seems to me that the Roslyn packages shouldn't necessarily be executed in parallel as part of a testing suite.